# How to alert all dynamic id's between a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have have a dynamic table here, each cell having different dynamic id's. How can i alert Dynamic id's between a range? Here i want to alert all id's between 1-1-3-Aug-2014 and 1-1-7-Aug-2014, starting and ending ids getting from heighlight class.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="1-1-3-Aug-2014" class="heighlight"></td>
            <td id="1-1-4-Aug-2014" class="heighlight"></td>
            <td id="1-1-5-Aug-2014" class="heighlight"></td>
            <td id="1-1-6-Aug-2014" class="heighlight"></td>
            <td id="1-1-7-Aug-2014" class="heighlight"></td>
            <td id="1-1-8-Aug-2014"></td>
            <td id="1-1-9-Aug-2014"></td>
            <td id="1-1-10-Aug-2014"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You want to fetch ids which have `highlight` class?

Comment: ya iam trying to alert between a range having class heighlight

Comment: @kannanD.S—your example isn't very good as the range can be selected using the class alone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/5/

Comment: You can use a selector like `.heighlight[id$=Aug-2004]` then filter that for the range `1-1-3` to `1-1-7`. Did you really mean "heighlight" or "highlight"?

Answer (score 1):

I did a sample code (no Jquery), not sure if this is what you're exactly looking for:

This code uses two variables for the range: `start` and `last` (which is the "day" in your "date" ids).
The values for each `td` with id's within the range and having the class `heighlight` will be alerted.

***[SAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uh956z9o/2/)***

```
 var start = 3, last = 9, //your range
    output="";

while ( start <= last ) {
    var id = "1-1-"+start+"-Aug-2014",
        elem = document.getElementById(id);    
    if ( elem.className == "heighlight" ) {
        output += "id: "+id+", value: "+elem.innerHTML + ", class= \"heighlight\"\n\n";       
    }    
    start++;
}

alert(output);
```

Comment: You also need to specify the *heighlight* class.

Comment: Do you mean, alerting the id's by using class?

Comment: No, the OP wants the ID range and *heighlight* class, not just the range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code:

This one's targeting all the `td`s with `heighlight` class and alerting their `id`s:

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1rsg1307/)***

JS:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName("heighlight"),
    output = "";

for ( i = 0; i < tds.length;i++ ) {
    output += tds[i].id + "\n\n"
}

alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you can do:

```
// Collect candidate elements
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.heighlight[id$=Aug-2014]');

// Filter for range
els = [].filter.call(els, function(el){
  var n = el.id.split('-')[2];
  return n >= 3 && n <= 7;
});
```

However that depends on browsers supporting CSS 3 selectors and passing host objects to native methods as *this*. jQuery has something similar:

```
var els = $('.heighlight[id$=Aug-2014]').filter(function(i, el) {
  var n = el.id.split('-')[2];
  return n >= 3 && n <= 7;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Case 1. If all the elements have the `heighlight` class:

```
$("td.heighlight").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Case 2. If all the elements do not have the `heighlight` class, but at least 2 have:

```
var firstElement = $("td.heighlight:eq(0)");
var elementsBetween = firstElement.nextUntil('td.heighlight');
var lastElement = elementsBetween.last().next();

alert(firstElement.attr("id"));
elementsBetween .each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
alert(lastElement.attr("id"));
```

[JSFiddle from case 2](http://jsfiddle.net/upcw6m4j/)

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it's good to assume there's no other element with the same class, `td.heighlight` has less side effects. IMO the best would be to assign an id for the table and use: `$('#someTableId .heighlight')`.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain, what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.heighlight').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id'));   
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The **jQuery** way

```
$('.heighlight').each(function () {
    alert( $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/b17x477k/1)**